# QSSTV Audio Device Enumeration

Tags: linux, sstv

My new desktop system running Clear Linux with the latest version of qsstv and hamlib is having a problem with audio device enumeration. This is because qsstv filters the audio device list as follows:

```
if(
         !deviceName.contains("surround",Qt::CaseInsensitive)
         && !deviceName.contains("dmix",Qt::CaseInsensitive)
         && !deviceName.contains("front",Qt::CaseInsensitive)
         && !deviceName.contains("plughw",Qt::CaseInsensitive)
         && !deviceName.contains("null",Qt::CaseInsensitive)
         && !deviceName.contains("hdmi",Qt::CaseInsensitive)
         && !deviceName.contains("sysdefault",Qt::CaseInsensitive)
         && !deviceName.contains("dsnoop",Qt::CaseInsensitive)
)
```

Every one of my devices except S/PDIF is eliminated by this from the audio device dropdowns. S/PDIF is a digital audio output which is tough enough, but my motherboard does not provide a breakout for it so it useless for any purpose, not just qsstv.

I could just patch around this code but building from source has been difficult (4 hours in so far) due to some issues with a new version of openjpeg. I was reading the WSJT-X source and saw that the devices are enumerated in the same way without the above filtering. It is working great on the new computer.

Has anyone else experienced this and and hopefully worked around it somehow?

Update: I finally managed to hack my way through a source build and the patch works fine.

73,
Chris VE3NRT

Here's the list of devices present on the computer. Only the last one is seen by qsstv.

```
null
Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC1220 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=4
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=5
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 5
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=6
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 6
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=7
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 7
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=8
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 8
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=9
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 9
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=10
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 10
    HDMI Audio Output
sysdefault:CARD=CODEC
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
```

Comment: Hi @DavidHoelzer! The question seems to be about qsstv to me, and we talk about getting ham software to work all the time, so in my opinion this is the best site for the question.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com, @Deepstop!  I see you've been lurking for a while ;)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you found a patch that fixes your problem.  If you wrote the patch, I hope that you submit it to the project so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: Hi there. I've posted a related but different question on the Clear Linux forum and to my surprise and delight they have picked up this issue and are looking at incorporating a patch into the distro, as well as making the build easier by adding header files to the hamlib package in the amateur radio bundle. I've also emailed the developer with all of the above and more. Now if I could only get a decent logging program in Linux... Unfortunately Clear Linux doesn't have the build environment for cqrlog which appears to be the best candidate I've run across so far.

Comment: I'm delighted to hear that your feedback will help others!

Comment: It's a bit lengthy to explain here, but this discussions continues on the Clear Linux Forum (https://community.clearlinux.org/t/hacked-my-way-through-a-problem-how-to-clean-up/7285)